# Coucbase to Kafka source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, couchbase, apache-kafka-connect

I have used kafka source connector to get the documents from Couchbase to kafka. These documents are then replicated to Mongo DB.

Couchbase --> Source Connector --> Kafka --> Sink Connector ---> Mongo

If the source connector is down then how to again synch all the documents to Kafka?

Is there any get and touch functionality that can agian event out all the changes made during the down period to the kafka topic?

Comment: This would depend on how the source connector knows what to read. Does it track timestamps or incrementing ids? Or only pull new records as changes are made to the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about processing the document changes that occurred while the source connector was down, then you don't need to do anything. Kafka Connect stores the state (offsets) of the source connector and will restore the StreamTask state and continue from where it left off. The Couchbase source connector supports this, as we can see in the code [here](https://github.com/couchbase/kafka-connect-couchbase/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/connect/kafka/CouchbaseSourceTask.java#L123), which is then used [here](https://github.com/couchbase/kafka-connect-couchbase/blob/master/src/main/java/com/couchbase/connect/kafka/CouchbaseReader.java#L193) to initialize the DCP stream with the saved offsets.

If you're asking how to reset the connector and re-stream the entire bucket from the beginning, that's actually not as easy. As far as I know, there is no built-in way in Kafka to reset a connector's offsets - there is a KIP under review related to that: [KIP-199](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-199%3A+Add+Kafka+Connect+offset+tool) Barring official support, the best way I know of resetting the connector state is either change the config to use a different topic for saving the offsets, which is hacky and leaves the old offsets as a potential problem, or actually edit the saved offsets as described [here](https://rmoff.net/2019/08/15/reset-kafka-connect-source-connector-offsets/). I would never advocate doing either of those on a production system, so use your own judgement.